# set tab-stop = 2 in vim permanently for a file

Tags: vim, tabs, permanent, tab-size

How to set the tab size as 2 for a file permanently in vim as whenever I open a file in other editors like nano or upload the file in github then my indentations are all incorrent whenever I try to resize the tab to 2 for an existing file which has all incorrect indentations. The tab-stop=2 does not permanently resizes the tab and I see all incorrect indentation when I open the same file in nano or view it in github.

Comment: One option might be to turn tabs to spaces with `set expandtab` and have vim insert a certain number of spaces when you hit tab with `set softtabstop=2` (or however many spaces you want per tab press. Whatever number you use, you should make tabstop the same (in this example, `set tabstop=2`). Another useful thing would be `set shiftwidth=2` (or whatever number you want) to make the `<` and `>` commands consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Tabs don't have an inherent size so it is up to each program to decide how to display them and there is simply no way to guarantee that a tab will always look the same everywhere.

This is precisely the main issue people have with tabs: you can tell $SOME_TOOL and $SOME_OTHER_TOOL that a tab takes two spaces but that setting *can't* possibly be carried over to *every* tool.

Modelines are editor-specific (and they are too intrusive anyway) and Editorconfig is not universally supported so there is really no universal solution beyond using spaces for indentation.